# Error using Product.reindex with OpenSearch and Elasticsearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, opensearch, searchkick, fly

I'm currently working on a project where I'm using the Product.reindex method in Ruby on Rails with OpenSearch and Elasticsearch. However, I'm encountering an error that I'm having trouble resolving. The error message I'm receiving is:

```
/Users/samroberts/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/opensearch-transport-2.1.0/lib/opensearch/transport/transport/base.rb:227:in `__raise_transport_error': [429] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"cluster_block_exception","reason":"index [products_development_20230714221422184] blocked by: [TOO_MANY_REQUESTS/12/disk usage exceeded flood-stage watermark, index has read-only-allow-delete block];"}],"type":"cluster_block_exception","reason":"index [products_development_20230714221422184] blocked by: [TOO_MANY_REQUESTS/12/disk usage exceeded flood-stage watermark, index has read-only-allow-delete block];"},"status":429} (OpenSearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::TooManyRequests)
```

Additionally, I'm experiencing the same issue on the server, which also uses Elasticsearch. The specific error message I receive on the server is:

```
Searchkick::ImportError: {“type”=>“cluster_block_exception”, “reason”=>“index [rgg_products_development_20230714195645911] blocked by: [TOO_MANY_REQUESTS/12/disk usage exceeded flood-stage watermark, index has read-only-allow-delete block];”} on item with id ‘114’
```

It seems that the error is related to disk usage however on the server i'm only using 150 mb and on my computer i have 28gb availble!

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this error. Thank you in advance for your help!

I have tried to use chatgpt to help me out here but got no help so far with it.